# get data from internet and push to array flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So, here is my code.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'albums/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    //var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({@required this.userId, @required this.id, @required this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get Album values (userId, id, title) and push it to an array so i can do some math...

But i dont know how to do it, i manage to display the data on screen with Builder() method, but not acess it individually.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ???.... Do you just wants to add the response to a list ??

Comment: Yes, an array or a list would work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to make it work by creating a function and passing the values as parameter inside the factory.

Then, in the function "foo", i get the values and print it.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'albums/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({@required this.userId, @required this.id, @required this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    foo(json['userId'], json['id'], json['title']);
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

void foo(userId, id, title) async {
  final user = title;
  print(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work!

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  
 var response = await http.get('https;//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' + '/albums/1');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   
    return Album data = Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

Album AlbumFromJson(String str) => TrueOrFalse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String AlbumToJson(TrueOrFalse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({@required this.userId, @required this.id, @required this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "userId": userId,
"id": id,
"title": title,
  };
}
```

Comment: how can i acess the values from another class?